# "do" function in Perl

Tags: perl

Recently, I have a perl script which calls another perl script using "do"; ie.

`do "./script2.pl $arg1 $arg2";`

My script2.pl was designed to consume 2 arguments.

However, calling script2.pl in the way above will not pass the arguments into script2.pl.

I know there is another way using "system", but my script1.pl needs to get some variable values through "require".

Can I actually use "do" and pass in the arguments to my script2?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "needs to get some variable values through require". Show the code.

Comment: Don't you mean "I want args in @ARGV?" In which case, why don't you put them in @ARGV?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the script you are calling is expecting arguments, it will expect them in the variable `@ARGV`. If you are using `do`, the `@ARGV` in the calling script will be visible in the called script.

```
{
    local @ARGV = ($arg1, $arg2);
    do './script2.pl';
}
```

Using `local` like this will restore the old values of `@ARGV` at the end of the block, kind of like saying

```
@ARGV_old = @ARGV;
@ARGV = ($arg1,$arg2);
do './script2.pl';
@ARGV = @ARGV_old;
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer, is you probably want to use `system()` if you want to call another script with arguments:

```
use autodie;
system('./script2.pl', $arg1, $arg2);

# OR if you don't want to install autodie from CPAN
system('./script2.pl', $arg1, $arg2) == 0
    or die "cannot run script2.pl: $!";
```

If you need to share an interpreter, you probably want to do this completely differently. For example, for quick scripts, I sometimes use `require` like this:

```
our $SHARED_VALUE = 0;
our $OTHER_VALUE = 42;

require 'script2.pl';
```

In `script2.pl`, you can define:

```
our ($SHARED_VALUE, $OTHER_VALUE);
```

and when `script2.pl` is loaded through the require, these variables will be set. This is still not the best way.

Better still, is to use a package to share code, but that would extend beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: `autodie` is a core module from perl v5.10.1.

Comment: Good point. On the other hand, most folks still use a 5.8 release of Perl from 12-15 years ago for some reason, so you still have to point out the alternative.

Comment: The scales have tipped in favour of 5.10 two years ago. http://imgur.com/lcUvL (source: Perl Survey 2010)

Comment: Solaris is the culprit. Solaris 9 came with Perl 5.6 and 5.00503. Solaris 10 offers Perl 5.8.4 and 5.6. Solaris 11 does come with version 5.10.0, but didn't come out until November of last year. How did they do that Perl survey? Was it a self reported thing? Was it advertised on Perl heavy sites?  I can imagine that survey being skewed towards newer releases since people on older Perl releases might not be that active in the Perl community.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share variables, then they should be in the same module.  Otherwise you're writing spaghetti.

If you want to structure your code so that one file encapsulates some functions, then make it a module and have "use module" to include it.

Comment: script2 is a very long script which is designed to do some other jobs and many other people are using this script; script1 is written by me which I just want to get the values of some variables in script2. I cannot modify that script2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also inject your script in main program with

```
 eval `cat ./script2.pl`
```

such way it can access all scope variables of main program.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not pass arguments to a perl script with `do`.

Comment: Thank you. Then in what way I can approach this?